# How do i turn off email notifications on my laptop?

Tags: mail.app, email, ical

I keep getting email's notifying me of my upcoming meetings. This would be fine, but i never asked it to do this.

I use Gmail for email and Google Calendar for my scheduling. On my laptop Mail.app and iCal *are* linked to my Google account although I never use either of them.

Can someone point me in the right direction for turning email notifications off?

Answer (score 2):

1. sign in to google calendar at http://google.com/calendar
2. Click on the 'gear' icon at the top right and choose 'Calendar Settings'
3. Click on 'Calendars'
4. Click on 'Notifications' for the appropriate calendar
5. look for 'Event reminders' and remove the 'By default, remind me via [Email]' entry

Comment: thanks, i went in there and it the checkbox was already unchecked.. is it possible that Mail.App is doing it on its own, ignoring the Google settings?

Comment: Not likely. I would open up iCal and see what's going on. If you have used BusyCal, I would also open that up too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer on this page might help, especially the 4th suggestion: http://www.quora.com/OS-X-10-8-Mountain-Lion/Is-there-a-way-to-completely-disable-OS-X-Mail-app-to-fire-up-and-send-Calendar-notifications

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.